# Html5 date input - disallow partial date input

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an input type="date", that is not required. The date can either be left empty (mm/dd/yyyy) or valid. When the user enters only part of the date (e.g. month and day, without year), it is silently treated as empty, but valid. What I want instead is to treat this as invalid, and alert the user. Is this possible?

```
<input type="date" id="applicationDate" class="form-control" ng-model="emp.applicationDate">
```

Comment: You can use pattern to validate it..

Comment: ng-pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input name="shipmentDate" 
       ng-pattern='/^[0,1]?\d{1}\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))$/'
       required ng-model="shipment.ShipmentDate" type="text">
    <span ng-show="form.shipmentDate.$error.required">Date Required!</span>
    <span ng-show="form.shipmentDate.$error.pattern">Incorrect Format, should be MM/DD/YYYY</span>

    <input class="btn-primary" ng-hide="!form.$valid" type="submit" value="Create">
```

Here is the fiddle for you :-
http://jsfiddle.net/zo8aLh03/1/

Comment: You can remove required if you wanted i just added it for button at the end of form.